# Entered correct data but log in keeps failing c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to c# asp.net. got this code from a tutorial but I am getting an error. My label says log in failed though I entered the correct data. Please help me :( and it says: Object reference not set to an instance of an object when I entered an incorrect data.

here's my ConnectionClass.cs

```
public class ConnectionClass
 {
 private static SqlConnection conn;
 private static SqlCommand command;

static ConnectionClass()
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CoffeeDBConnectionString"].ToString();
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    command = new SqlCommand("", conn);
}

public static User LoginUser(string login, string password)
{ 
    //Check if user exists
    string query = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SkyMusic.dbo.user WHERE username = '{0}'", login);
    command.CommandText = query;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        int numofUsers = (int) command.ExecuteScalar();

        if (numofUsers < 1)
        {
            //user exists, check if the passwords match
            query = string.Format("SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = '{0}'", login);
            command.CommandText = query;
            string dbPassword = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            if (dbPassword == password)
            {
                //Passwords match
                query = string.Format("SELECT email, user_type FROM users WHERE username = '{0}'", login);
                command.CommandText = query;

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                User user = null;

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string email = reader.GetString(0);
                    string type = reader.GetString(1);

                    user = new User(login, password, email, type);
                }
                return user;
            }
            else
            {
                //passwords do not match
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

}
```

my login:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
 </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

<div id="formcont">
<table>
<tr>
<td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Username:"></asp:Label></td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="142px"></asp:TextBox></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Password:"></asp:Label></td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="142px"></asp:TextBox></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"></br><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Log In" />
    <br />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>Don't have an account? Click <a href="Register.aspx" runat="server">here</a>!</p>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

and

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        User user = ConnectionClass.LoginUser(txtUname.Text, txtPass.Text);


        if (user != null)
        {
            Session["login"] = user.login;
            Session["type"] = user.type;
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "Login Failed";
        }
     }
```

please help :(
here's my db
id, username, password, email, user_type

Comment: this might help http://www.codingdefined.com/2014/06/object-reference-not-set.html

Comment: As I know, I am checking for nulls. :(

Comment: Use breakpoints and debug the program.

Comment: @Fel - Debug your code it'll provide you an answer within a minute!

Comment: Didn't you try to debug your code at all? Do you know from which line the error is thrown?

Comment: @Fel - `command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();` must be throwing error, if no password found then.

Comment: Hey @Fel I think your check, `if (numofUsers < 1)` is wrong. You see when the value is less than 1 which means wrong userID, you're checking for password. On the other hand when the value is 1 i.e., correct UserID you're directly throwing the `null` value. Change this condition to `if (numofUsers >= 1)`. You should be good to go.

Comment: Hi, @P.K.! Yes, it worked already. But when I enter wrong data, it gives me the null reference error. What part of the code should be fixed? :(

Comment: @Fel What's the current check condition you're using instead of `if (numofUsers < 1)` ??

Comment: if (numofUsers <= 1) @P.K.

Comment: Why `<=` ?? You should be using `if (numofUsers >= 1)`. if the value of **numofUsers** is less than 1, then it means wrong userID. SO there's no need to test for password. You're must be thrown from the line, `string dbPassword = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();` Since, the USerID is wrong the password will be null. Calling `.ToString()' on `null` will give you this error.

Comment: @Chaturvedi's > 0 worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems or error

**1. You can not login with correct credential:**

Check this.

```
if (numofUsers < 1)
    {
        //user exists, check if the passwords match
        query = string.Format("SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = '{0}'", login);
```

If no of user is less than 1 how can a user exists in system.

**2. Null reference error:**

In case user does not exists then this method returned null you should be handling null and showing **incorrect credential or user does not exists**

**EDIT**
Rahul seems to be correct in comments of question. Debug your code first.

**EDIT**

As per your comment you were using
if (numofUsers < 1)

then you changed to 
if (numofUsers <= 1)

Use it as
if (numofUsers > 0)

Comment: It worked. entering wrong data still shows an error. where do I handle that, what part of the code?

Comment: Line of code you should debug first and put break point at Button1_Click method, then navigate through code and find the exact line. Then you can find the error.

Comment: There are three use cases: 1) User exists and correct password. 2) User exists and incorrect password. 3) User does not exists. Last two cases should show incorrect login/password. Debug with these use cases.

Comment: Where will I put them, in my aspx.cs file?

Comment: Go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: It didn't help. Problem is I got this statement on Button1_click, that is supposed to fetch nulls but it don't work.

Comment: Change condition to if (numofUsers > 0)